# Decompose function- Seasonal Adjustment

Tags: r

in the decompose function, four graphs are created when plotted: the actual time series, estimated trend, estimated seasonal, and estimated error. Is the seasonal plot the result after seasonally adjusting?

Comment: do enough research before posting.

Answer (score 0):

From `?decompose`:

`The function first determines the trend component using a moving average (if ‘filter’ is ‘NULL’, a symmetric window with equal weights is used), and removes it from the time series. Then, the seasonal figure is computed by averaging, for each time unit, over all periods.  The seasonal figure is then centered.  Finally, the error component is determined by removing trend and seasonal figure (recycled as needed) from the original time series.`

Comment: Hi Fernando, thank you for your response. What I was really trying to understand, was whether the seasonal component was the seasonality or seasonal adjusted data. I received a response from another forum confirming that, this is the seasonality within the data.